# Why is the WL charged at Vccp for DRAM cell?

Tags: digital-logic, sdram, dram

Qouting from [Dynamic random-access memory - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory)

> Reading or writing a logic one requires the wordline is driven to a voltage greater than the sum of VCC and the access transistor's threshold voltage (VTH). This voltage is called VCC pumped (VCCP). The time required to discharge a capacitor thus depends on what logic value is stored in the capacitor. A capacitor containing logic one begins to discharge when the voltage at the access transistor's gate terminal is above VCCP. If the capacitor contains a logic zero, it begins to discharge when the gate terminal voltage is above VTH.

My question is, why does the WL need to be charged at VCCP (i.e VCC + Vth) and not at VCC? How does the capacitor discharging depend on WL voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word line (i.e., the gates of the cell transistors) needs to be charged to V<sub>CCP</sub> because the transistors wouldn't conduct any current if the corresponding storage capacitor is charged to V<sub>CC</sub>.

Remember, during the latter part of the read operation, the charges on the storage capacitors get refreshed from the sense amplifiers. The cell transistor must be allowed to pass this refresh charge back into the capacitor, and the only way to guarantee that this can happen for a stored "1" is to make sure all of the gates are at V<sub>CC</sub> + V<sub>TH</sub>.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I am still unable to understand why charge is passed to capacitor only when gate is at VCCP. Maybe I am missing something. If gate is VCC only, and charge to be passed is VCC, what is the issue?

Comment: An enhancement-mode MOSFET will only pass current if the gate-to-channel voltage is greater than its threshold voltage. When you're trying to charge a capacitor to Vcc (the channel voltage), the gate must therefore be Vcc + Vth.

Comment: So which region does the transistor operate? If its in linear region, then I can relate what you mentioned since VGS(VWL) > VDS(VCC) + Vth. But if its in saturation region then VWL < VCC + VTH.

Comment: Or in other words, VGS = VDSAT + Vth(n). So since VDSAT(VBL) is constant, gate voltage is the only tunable parameter hence it can either be greater or equal to VCC + vth?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand your question. What dos "VDSAT" have to do with it? Note that neither end (drain or source) of the transistor in question is grounded. One is connected to the capacitor and one is connected to the bit line. Indeed, their roles are pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can explain with equations why VCC+Vth is needed at gate for capacitor to charge. I thought the transistor is in saturation so I mentioned VDSAT.